# Yii2 минимальное значение в бд

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, запрос

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - не могу получить минимальное значение из бд, хотя с максимальным сложностей нет.
У меня в голосовании есть победитель и проигравший, определяю я их следующим образом:

```
public static function getWinner($poll_id)
{
    $winner = self::find()->where(['poll_id' => $poll_id])->andWhere(max(['count']))->one();
    return $winner;
}

public static function getLosers($poll_id)
{
    $losers = self::find()->where(['poll_id' => $poll_id])->andWhere(min(['count']))->one();
    return $losers;
}
```

Запросы идентичны, с разницей только в min и max.
После чего через консоль я вызываю
 `yii winner/competition`:

```
public function actionCompetition()
{
    $comp = ACompetition::find()->all();
    foreach ($comp as $item) {

        $endPrepareTimeStamp = strtotime($item->endofprepare);
        $endPollTimeStamp = strtotime($item->endofpoll);
        $currentTimeStamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

        $winner = AOption::getWinner($item->id);
        if (($currentTimeStamp > $endPrepareTimeStamp) && ($currentTimeStamp > $endPollTimeStamp)) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE a_competition SET winner = '$winner->user_name' WHERE id='$item->id'")->execute();
        }
        $losers = AOption::getLosers($item->id);
        if (($currentTimeStamp > $endPrepareTimeStamp) && ($currentTimeStamp > $endPollTimeStamp)) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE a_competition SET losers = '$losers->user_name' WHERE id='$item->id'")->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Победитель определяется правильно, а вот проигравший нет, получается что победитель является и проигравшим http://joxi.ru/Rmz5Q6btz0glrO.
Если сделать var_dump($losers), то выводит победителя. Хотя вот такой запрос в phpmyadmin возвращает правильное значение `` SELECT min(`count`) FROM a_option WHERE poll_id = 1 ``. Предполагаю что в запросе в модели что-то не так, но тогда почему max работает, а min нет? Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: Какие запросы генерирует AR смотрели?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan видимо вот это он http://joxi.ru/E2pLnJBHq95l2Y, потому что на 102 строке как раз идет функция getLosers(). И выводит не те значения что нужны.

Comment: А что мешает сделать так:

`$winner = self::find()->where(['poll_id' => $poll_id])->orderBy('count DESC')->one();`?

Comment: @MasterAlex ничего не мешает :) я о таком варианте не думал. Но это сработало, только в случае проигравшего нужно ASC. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyDunin, ну да, логично, что для проигравших делать обратную сортировку :)

Answer (score 1):

В where так просто не выйдет использовать min и max, тут необходимо делать вложенные запросы, не знаю вашу структуру, но что-то похожее у Вас должно быть:

```
public static function getWinner($poll_id)
{
    $subQuery = self::find()->max('count');
    $winner = self::find()->where(['poll_id' => $poll_id])->andWhere(['count' => $subQuery])->one();
    return $winner;
}

public static function getLosers($poll_id)
{
    $subQuery = self::find()->min('count');
    $losers = self::find()->where(['poll_id' => $poll_id])->andWhere(['count' => $subQuery])->one();
    return $losers;
}
```

Используйте [min](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#min()-detail) и [max](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#max()-detail) методы для подзапроса и потом результат используйте в основном запросе.

Comment: В AR запросы теперь нормальные, http://joxi.ru/KAg0JnPcZEKzrl , http://joxi.ru/V2VpvMdT4d8Grv . Но есть одно "но", определяется только один юзер, хоть и правильно http://joxi.ru/DrllMybcRVGQrP. Я вернул старый запрос для победителя и разделил actionCompetition(). Что бы отдельно определить победителя и проигравшего. С победителями тогда все ок, но вот проигравший только для второго голосования определился http://joxi.ru/v29DywXinZQWmG.
Буду делать, спасибо за наводку!